# How to get the sum of a row, whose datatype is varchar and its first character is "£"?

Tags: sql-server

I want sum of the row whose datatype is varchar & first character is £ like :

```
Total
£23.0
£13.0
£2.40
```

I am using this query:

```
select sum(cast(SUBSTRING(total,2,(LEN(total)))as int)) as Total from tbl_preorder
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hi Use below query, with same sequence as you mentioned above except datatype int to decimal.**

```
SELECT sum(cast(SUBSTRING(total, 2, ( LEN(total) ))AS DECIMAL(10, 2))) AS Total
FROM   tbl_preorder
```

Answer (score 3):

Your query doesn't work due to decimal digits and field length. Try this:

```
SELECT Sum(Cast(Replace(total, '£', '') AS DECIMAL(10, 2))) 
FROM   test 
WHERE total LIKE '£%'
```

and verify on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b5da7/1)

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the slightly more concise.

```
SELECT SUM(CAST(total AS MONEY))
FROM tbl_preorder
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/6583)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT sum(cast(stuff(total, 1,1,'') as decimal(10,2))) as Total 
FROM tbl_preorder
```

Answer (score 1):

You should consider that you really want to do this. If you have possibility, you should change the data type of that column to decimal, or maybe introduce a computed column (which either would be this value with string, or will be a decimal and do the substring on varchar column).

Comment: Thanks Botis ! but I want answer in the same scenario.

Answer (score 1):

hi hope this help thanks

SELECT SUM(CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,2), STUFF(total,1,1,''))) as Total from tbl_preorder